# What is the impact on GCP of changing a G Suite primary domain name and renaming users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm looking to change the primary domain of my G Suite instance. We have a GCP Organisation setup and a number of projects created and owned by users.

The intention is to change the primary domain of the G Suite instance and then rename users to the new domain.

I'm trying to workout if this will be seamless or it will impact:

The organisation node of GCP
ownership of projects etc

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

think it would barely affect GCP, because GSuite is something else.

see the [tutorial](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7009324?hl=en) - the project owner's email would be changed for `IAM`...

> Before renaming the super administrator account you're signed in with, be sure to record the new name somewhere safe. You will automatically be signed out upon renaming and will need the new super administrator name to sign back in.

side-effect should only be caused, when having project owners' email address hard-coded.

it should still be the same ID for the organization, no matter how it is being called.